# awk command not running after hitting enter

Tags: awk

I have a text file that resembles the following:

```
Question: What is.... ?

Answer:

Question: What is.... ?

Answer:
```

I am currently trying to insert some text after the 2nd `"Answer"`. I am currently using the following:

```
awk '{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++){    
    if ($i ~ /Answer:/)
       count++
    if (count == 2)
       sub(/Answer:/,"A's",$i)
  }
 }1' lab02.txt > tmp && mv tmp lab02.txt
```

This worked for the first `"Answer:` when I changed `count` to `1`. However when I run this as above, the command doesn't execute. It seems to be expecting more output...?

Also, what does the `1` in `}1' lab02.txt > tmp && mv tmp lab02.txt` mean?

I'm quite new to shell scripting so any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: The `1` is an awk idiom. Any true pattern runs the default action which is to print the line. `1` is a true pattern. It is cuddled up against the previous closing `}` out of general laziness (the good kind) and space considerations.

Comment: I know there's lots of very official-seeming documentation, including from the guys who invented the tool, that talk about awk scripts having the form `pattern { action }` but they are all wrong. Awk scripts have the form `condition { action }` and a "pattern" (either a keyword like `BEGIN` or an RE to be compared to `$0`) is just one possible condition . `1`, or any other non-zero number, in the context of a condition is a true condition in awk, just like it is in C and most other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an apostrophe in the middle of your awk command and that is throwing your shell's parsing of the command out of whack.

It sees the `'` at the end of `}1'` as starting a new string which is unfinished.

You need to escape that awk internal `'` from the shell.

Replace it with `'\''`.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue.. I tried escaping using just "\" but that didn't work. Thanks Etan :)

Comment: @Giri Correct. You cannot escape a single quote inside a single quoted string. Single quotes do not honor escapes of any sort.

Comment: Right so if you need one, use `\047` instead, e.g. `print "there\047s one!"`

Answer (score 1):

@EtanReisner answered your specific question but it sounds like your script shoud be written as:

```
$ awk '/Answer:/{ if (++cnt==2) $0 = "A\047s" } 1' file
Question: What is.... ?

Answer:

Question: What is.... ?

A's
```